# What is the "Optimize Response" connection string attribute used for?

Tags: optimization, connectivity, mdx, cube

My apologies if this is not the correct forum to be asking this in.

I am having trouble finding information regarding the "Optimize Response" connection string attribute. The most promising source of information I have found is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017), but it doesn't really make clear to me what the settings are, or how it will really impact an MDX query on the server side.

There are two cases for optimization? One is to use the "NormalTupleSet", which I can't even find what that is anywhere. The other is for when the slicers are empty. What do each of these really do? Would a client use the second option for empty slicers, when they are instead passing a subquery to the FROM clause?

Thank you for any help anyone can give me in this regard, especially if you can point me to accessible resources on the topic.